# String comparison in Perl

Tags: string, perl

I have an array of sequences:

```
@array = (AAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD,AEABCBBBCCECCDDDDD...); #up to 55 sequences
```

I want to compare each position of each sequence. In other words, first position of the sequences shown is A, so they are the same. I'd like to have a counter that indicates how many positions don't have the same letter for every string.

```
AAABB
AAABC
AAABB #5th position is not equal, so result is 1.

print $counter -----> 1.
```

I know how to do it with 2 sequences:

```
my $string1 = 'AAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD';
my $string2 = 'AEABBBBBCCECCDDDDD';
my $result = '';
for(0 .. length($string1)) {
    my $char = substr($string2, $_, 1);
    if($char ne substr($string1, $_, 1)) {
        $counter++;
    }
}
print $counter;
```

The problem is that I have 55 sequences in an array.

Comment: Show what have you done yourself?

Comment: What do you mean by "not the same"? Not the same as what? You say the 3rd position is not equal, but not equal to what?

Comment: No idea how to do it.

Comment: Do you mean all elements of the array must be identical? If so, just compare element 1 to element 0, then compare element 2 to element 0, then compare element 3 to element 0...

Comment: @MarkSetchell I guess that's what he means... OP: Please read about substrings: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html

Comment: You can't do much better than the naïve approach of using two nested loops (for each position, for each sequence). This is pretty trivial. Where's your attempt?

Comment: I've improved my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right approach in the first part of your question: Use an array.

```
my @strings = qw( AAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD AEABBBBBCCECCDDDDD );
my $result = '';

my $counter = 0;
for my $pos (0 .. length($strings[0])) {
    my $char = substr($strings[0], $pos, 1);
    for my $i (1..$#strings) {
       if (substr($strings[$i], $pos, 1) ne $char) {
          ++$counter;
          last;
       }
    }
}

print "$counter\n";
```

Comment: I'd like to skip the loop when a nonmatch is found (after `counter++`), so the following position is examined. Is that possible?

Comment: See in `perldoc perlsyn` 'next', and 'last'.

Answer (score 0):

Huh? If every letter has to be the same in every one of the 55 or so strings, there is no need to look at individual letters, surely? The whole strings must be equal, so this answers the question:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw(AAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD AEABBBBBCCECCDDDDD APPLE); 
for my $i (1..$#array){
   print "$array[$i] isn't same as $array[0]\n" if $array[$i] ne $array[0];
}
```

Comment: I need the number of differences.